# How to Get Data in Pictures

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

How to Get Data in Pictures？
I don't know how to get the data in innerHTML？

I tried with the following code, but it came out as a null。

```
const a = document.getElementsByClassName('v-line').item(0)。[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please provide a code example and more information as to what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: const a = document.getElementsByClassName('v-line');
    console.log(a);

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('v-line').item(0).attr('src') i guess?

Comment: I tried your method, but it made a mistake. Cannot read property 'attr' of null，

Comment: Thats because there are no elements with said class. Look if you are on angular you arent supposed to do this like this. Google @viewchild maybe on angular. If I help you I would only be helping you write bad code